# State ReactJS and render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, state, setstate

I'm studying chapter [State and lifecycle in reactJS](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) with Clock class and I don't understand why I can re-render my variables "myFirstNumber, mySecondNumber, myWord"  which are not states when I use this code in CodePen:

```js
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: new Date(),
    };
    this.mySecondNumber = 0;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.myFirstNumber = 0;
    this.myWord = "Start";
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );

  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      date: new Date(),

    });
        this.myFirstNumber += 1;
       this.mySecondNumber += 1;
    if (this.myFirstNumber ===5) {
      this.myWord = "Finish";
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
        <h2>myFirstNumber from ComponentDidMount: {this.myFirstNumber}</h2>
        <h2>mySecondNumber from constructor: {this.mySecondNumber}</h2>
        <h2>myWord: {this.myWord}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Clock />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The render method render all DOM each seconde for my variables which are not states ?

Comment: State variables or not, they are still variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call this.setState function, the DOM gets rerendered. Here the DOM is getting updated every second when this.state.date gets changed through this.setState, showing new values. However, if you keep date outside of state, you can see that the DOM no longer rerenders, same result if you want to change "myWord" or "firstNumber" without changing anything in state.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `tick()` the `setState` part is what triggers the re-render and that will process everything, state or not.

Answer (score 0):

In `componentDidMount()` you schedule interval which triggers `tick()` function every second. Inside this function you update component's state by invoking `setState()` and passing current time as a new state value. Moreover, you modify some local variables of the class. When arguments passed to `setState()` are processed by JS engine, what happens asynchronously, not immediately after `setState()` is called, the component updates its state.

Then the `render()` function is called by the framework. The `render()` function returns output which reflects the current values of all variables requested inside `render()` function. If you didn't call `setState()` inside `tick()` method then you wouldn't see any changes even though you modify `myFirstNumber` and other variables after each second.